# NLog.Web view component name

Tags: nlog

I have a page where we have multiple view components. I made a change on some components at the same time and in the log I was getting a warning. However in the log I can not see the viewcomponent name.

I am using `${aspnet-request-url}` and `${aspnet-mvc-action}` but they do not point me to the right view component. They are the action and the url to the original page and not the viewcomponent

Is there a way for NLog to provide the viewcomponent name?

I should mention that the warning is from a framework and not written in my code so I can not just add the viewcomponent name in the message. Also using the stacktrace doesn't help because its also from the framework and no call from my code is displayed, hence the reason I need the viewcomponent name.

Comment: Have you tried [${aspnet-mvc-controller}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-MVC-Controller-Layout-Renderer) ?

Comment: @RolfKristensen since ${aspnet-mvc-action} did not work, of course that the ${aspnet-mvc-controller} will not work also